# Ready made package.json & gulpfile.js (gulp)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web, gulp

https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-freelancer

When I download this template, I have ready made package.json & gulpfile.js.
How can I install all devDependencies? Should I use defaul construction for every plugin:

> npm i [plugin_name] [another_plugin_name] --save-dev

or another quick command?

Shoud I begin work with

> gulp init

?

Comment: Running `$ npm install` without any flags installs both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running

> npm install  **or**  npm i

will install both dependencies and dev dependencies